# Calling UIBarButton icons as images in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, icons, cell

I would like to use the system folder icon (`UIBarButtonSystemItemOrganize`) as the image on the left side of a table cell. Is there any way to call this icon in such a way that it can be used in `cell.imageView.image`?

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to provide your own images. There are numerous free and paid icon sets that available provide similar icons.